# is it electronegativity or a difference in charge which produces current

Tags: batteries

In a battery are electrons generated at the negative electrode due to chemical reactions and do they flow to the positive electrode due to a difference in electronegativity of the electrodes? Is an electric field generated as a result?

I always thought it was due to a difference in charge between terminals which created an electric field from positive to negative, is this wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More apt chemistry term to be taken into account is standard reduction potential. Not electronegativity. It's a measure of ability of an atom to get reduced i.e., gain an electron. The electrode with more reduction potential is taken as cathode, where reduction takes place. And the electrode with lesser reduction potential is taken as anode, where oxidation takes place. In a battery, both reduction and oxidation reactions takes place simultaneously to produce current through the external circuit (known as Half reactions, and together known as Redox Reaction). So that at anode electrons are generated , and at cathode these electrons are gained. The difference between the reduction potentials of cathode and anode makes up the cell potential or voltage of the battery. This is responsible for the electric field from cathode/positive to anode/negative of the battery.

Answer (score 1):

If you change "electronegativity" into "standard potential", both of those explanations are true - the first one is from a chemical standpoint, the second from an electrical one.

The difference in the electrodes' [standard potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential) forces electrons into the negative pole of the battery and pulls them out of the positive one. Due to this chemical process, there are more electrons in the negative electrode than in the positive one. This of course creates an electric field between the two battery terminals, resulting in a voltage between them, which can be used by an attached load.

Due to the electric field, current flows through the load, transporting electrons from the negative electrode to the positive one. The electrochemical processes in the battery will then replace the missing electrons in the negative electrode and pull out the extra ones from the positive electrode, thereby keeping the flow of electrons through the load going.

Comment: Is the more electronegative electrode not the positive one?

Comment: Actually, I mixed up "electronegativity" and "standard potential". It's the standard potential of the electrode that causes the current flow, not the electronegativity.

Answer (score 0):

> Do they flow to the positive electrode due to a difference in
>   electronegativity of the electrodes?

Electronegativity [from here](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/netorial/rottosen/tutorial/modules/intermolecular_forces/01review/review4.htm): -

> Electronegativity is a measure of an atom's ability to attract the
>   shared electrons of a covalent bond to itself. If atoms bonded
>   together have the same electronegativity, the shared electrons will be
>   equally shared. If the electrons of a bond are more attracted to one
>   of the atoms (because it is more electronegative), the electrons will
>   be unequally shared. If the difference in electronegativity is large
>   enough, the electrons will not be shared at all; the more
>   electronegative atom will "take" them resulting in two ions and an
>   ionic bond.

As far as I can tell this has little to do with free electron movement as seen in the flow of current. Electronegativity is the force that attracts atoms to form covalent bonds.

Comment: Electronegativity also defines which electrode will be the anode/cathode of a [galvanic cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell).

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yes but it doesn't produce the flow of free electrons aka current.